# MySQL VS2019 mysqlclient link - unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm using VS2019 C++ compiler attempting to build a simple MySQL client program - latest version 8.

I'm calling 3 MySQL functions - init, real_connect, and close.

I'm getting 3 unresolved external symbol errors.  I'm building X64 in debug.  I've set the LIB path and told the linker about mysqlclient.lib.  I want to use the old MySQL C API.

[Doc on Building C client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html)
The document states that the lib was built by Oracle using VS2015 - therefore I must also use VS2015.

THAT does not sound right.

The doc also states that the supplied mysqlclient.lib was NOT built using debug so I CANNOT use debug.

THAT does not sound right.

For years I have been statically linking to libraries that were compiled using a different version of VS and built in release mode with my program being built in debug.

Is Oracle compiling their mysqlclient.lib in a way so that those statement above are really true?

Thanks for your wisdom and comments.

Comment: For the first part, dlls and libs compiled with other compilers can lead to errors and is not recommended, but nothing hinders you to compile it yourself or to try it. everey compiler generation has its new features and sometimes have incompatibilities with their.predecessor.

Comment: One thing missing from your question is the actual error message. From your presentation, there seems to be a reasonable chance that your interpretation is correct, but why not copy the messages (as text) into your question to remove all doubts?